# Opening multiple word documents on button click using JS/Primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces, microsoft-edge

I am working on a Primefaces (6.2.17) project that is quite a few years old now and that has been using the Internet-Explorer-Mode offered in Edge until now. We now want to switch to Edge (without IE-Mode) and of course this causes a bunch of problems.
One such problem is the opening of multiple word documents from our fileserver with a button click. Here is how we have been doing this until now:

We use the [office uri schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) and Javascript's `window.open()` function to open word documents, which would look like this `window.open("window.open(" + url + ", '_blank')"` , with URL looking like this: `:ofe|u| <path to worddoc on our fileserver>` .

This approach works both in IE-Modus as well as normal Edge, however, in IE-Modus we used to be able to make multiple such calls based on one button click (opening multiple word documents). If I try to do the same thing in Edge, I can see these messages in the browser-console:

> Launched external handler for
> 'ms-word:ofe|u|https://pathToDocument.doc'
>
> Not allowed to launch
> 'ms-word:ofe|u|https://pathToAnotherDocument.doc' because a user
> gesture is required.

So it works for one element, but further elements would require user interaction. Is there any way to circumvent this? Or generally any other way I could use to have the user download multiple word documents based on a single button click (e.g using Primefaces p:fileDownload maybe)?

Comment: Since PrimeFaces 10 Ajax downloading is supported. You could have a look at the implementation and could do something similar. Instead of outputting JavaScript to download one file, you could output script do download several files. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/6267/files

Comment: @JasperdeVries Unfortunatelly I forgot to add that I am Primefaces 6.2.17 (I updated the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called **flood protection**, which is intentional to prevent spamming the user with multiple prompts and limits it to one per gesture. It is an expected behavior in browsers like Edge and Chrome.

The only solution/workaround is to apply a group policy called [DoNotSilentlyBlockProtocolsFromOrigins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#donotsilentlyblockprotocolsfromorigins) in Microsoft Edge. The value should be something like: `[{"allowed_origins": ["example.com", "http://www.example.com:8080"], "protocol": "ms-word"}]`. After that, you should be able to circumvent the error.